# Need Help in updating mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **table x** with the below fields,

```
n_i int(10) NOT NULL,
n_m longtext,
n_t varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
n_s varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
n_c int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
n_d datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

Data:

1, ABC has kept Hold rating on John Inc for target of $ 125 over a 12 month horizon from the current market price of $ 101., Hold John Inc for target of $ 125: ABC, ABC PCG, 1, 1/27/2006 22:55

2, RB Research has kept Buy rating on Johnson (New York) Inc for target of $ 80 over a 12 month horizon from the current market price of $ 64., Buy Johnson (New York) Inc for target of $ 80: RB Research, RB Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:03

3, XYZ Research has kept Buy rating on John & John Manufacturing (USA) Inc, a subsidiary of John & John Inc for target of $ 340 from the current market price of $ 270., Buy John & John Manufacturing (USA) Inc for target of Rs.340: XYZ Research, XYZ Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:06

4, ABCDE Research has upgraded Johnson (New York) Inc to Buy with a target of $ 1000 from the current market price of $ 750., Buy Johnson (New York) Inc for target of $ 1000: ABCDE Research, ABCDE Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:10

5, JKL Private Client Research has kept Buy rating on John2 Inc, parent company of John & John Manufacturing (USA) Inc with a target price of $ 295 from the current market price of $ 276., Buy John2 Inc for target of $ 295: JKL Private Client Research, JKL Private CLient Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:12

I would like to create the below **table y** with data from above table plus a new field **n_sy**. The search criteria is a string say, **BSSN** which will be taken from **table z** and searched in fields **n_t** and **n_m** of **table x** and if found field **n_sy** in **table y** would be updated with corresponding field data **"BSIS"** from **table z**. Also, the field **"n_sy"** should be able to hold more than one value. :-(

```
n_i int(10) NOT NULL,
n_m longtext,
n_t varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
n_s varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
n_c int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
n_d datetime DEFAULT NULL,
n_sy text NOT NULL
```

Data:

1, ABC has kept Hold rating on John Inc for target of $ 125 over a 12 month horizon from the current market price of $ 101., Hold John Inc for target of $ 125: ABC, ABC PCG, 1, 1/27/2006 22:55, **ABCD12345J**

2, RB Research has kept Buy rating on Johnson (New York) Inc for target of $ 80 over a 12 month horizon from the current market price of $ 64., Buy Johnson (New York) Inc for target of $ 80: RB Research, RB Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:03, **ABCD34567L**

3, XYZ Research has kept Buy rating on John & John Manufacturing (USA) Inc, a subsidiary of John & John Inc for target of $ 340 from the current market price of $ 270., Buy John & John Manufacturing (USA) Inc for target of Rs.340: XYZ Research, XYZ Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:06, **"ABCD56789A, ABCD45678M"**

4, ABCDE Research has upgraded Johnson (New York) Inc to Buy with a target of $ 1000 from the current market price of $ 750., Buy Johnson (New York) Inc for target of $ 1000: ABCDE Research, ABCDE Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:10, **ABCD34567L**

5, JKL Private Client Research has kept Buy rating on John2 Inc, parent company of Johnson (New York) Inc with a target price of $ 295 from the current market price of $ 276., Buy John2 Inc for target of $ 295: JKL Private Client Research, JKL Private CLient Research, 1, 1/27/2006 23:12, **"ABCD23456K, ABCD34567L"**

Table z

```
`BSCe` double DEFAULT NULL,
`BSSI` text,
`BSSN` text,
`BSSt` text,
`BSGr` text,
`BSFV` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`BSIS` text,
`BSIn` text,
`BSInst` text,
`NSSy` text,
`NSSc` text,
`NSSer` text,
`NSDOL` text,
`NSPUV` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`NSMktL` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`NSIS` text,
`NSEFV` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
```

12345, ABCD, John Inc, A, B, 10, ABCD12345J, Mine, E, J12345, John, T, 10-Oct-2019, 10, 1, ABCD12345J, 10

12346, XYZ, John2 Inc, A, B, 10, ABCD23456K, Iron, E, J12346, John2, T, 11-Jan-2020, 10, 1, ABCD23456K, 10

12347, JKL, Johnson (New York) Inc, A, B, 10, ABCD34567L, Electricty, E, J12347, John3, T, 7-Dec-2019, 10, 1, ABCD34567L, 10

12348, IJK, John & John Inc, A, B, 10, ABCD45678M, Mine, E, J12348, John & John, T, 19-Apr-2019, 10, 1, ABCD45678M, 10

12349, EFGH, John & John Manufacturing (USA) Inc, A, B, 10, ABCD56789A, IT, E, J12349, John & John Manufacturing Inc, T, 29-May-2019, 10, 1, ABCD56789A, 10

Looking for your help, as the MYSQL table is fairly large.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful in your explanation.

Comment: Theproblem with your last requirement, you can use json to store such multiple data, but it is always discouraged , because it is a pain to edit and replace data., don't use table y make a table that holds teh id if table x and the new values, and that can eventually normalized further

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use below query,

1. Creates the table with structure of x

   ```
   create table y as select * from table x;
   ```
2. Adds column column n_sy

   ```
   alter table y add n_sy text NOT NULL;
   ```
3. Updates BSSN from z to n_sy in y

   ```
   update y
   inner join z
   on (z.BSSN = y.n_t)
   set y.n_sy = z.BSIS;
   ```
4. Updates BSSN from z to n_sy in y to hold more than one value

   ```
   update y
   inner join z
   on (z.BSSN = y.n_m)
   set y.n_sy = y.n_sy || ',' || z.BSIS;
   ```

Comment: that is a bad idea first of all create a redundant table with the same information, a simple table that hiolds id of table yx and teh vaules is more than enough and normalized

Comment: The field BSSN is not there in table y, so how will your query work? I want to use z.BSSN field to query x and then update the new field in table y. Also, going forward only table y will be used. So, there is no redundant data.

Comment: Modified the query